# File descriptor automatically updated to end of file

Tags: c, linux, file, io

Consider this example (for brevity's sake, I've omitted headers and error checking):

```c
int main() {
    int fd;

    fd = open("dump", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if ( fork() > 0 ) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Current offset: %li\n", (long)lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        write(fd, "zz", 2);
    }
    else {
        write(fd, "hello\n", 6);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

This program (run on Linux) prints

```
Current offset: 6
```

to the terminal and

```
hello
zz%
```

to `dump` (`%` signifying the lack of a newline character).

Why doesn't `dump` contain

```
zzllo
```

?

My thinking is, after `fork`, there are two file descriptors to the same process but each with its own offset.  Why does writing to one descriptor affect the other?

Comment: That's what `fork` does and is documented in the man page. The two processes share the same file position because the `open` is done _before_ the `fork`. Either use `pwrite` or have each process do its own [private] `open`

Comment: The processes are _racing_. The parent will probably win the race and you will get: `hello\nzz` (as you did). But, you _could_ get: `zzhello\n` instead.

Comment: @CraigEstey, doesn't that contradict your first comment?

Comment: You want to use SEEK_SET not SEEK_CUR.  SEEK_SET is offset from the beginning of the file, SEEK_CUR is from the file's current position which will have been modified by the writing of  "Hello"

Comment: @DanielWalker It doesn't. Either `hello\n` or `zz` is written first and because of the shared filedescription, the shared position gets updated after each `write` and so there's no overwriting (notice Craig Estey wrote `zzhello\n` not `zzello\n`).

Comment: If you use the `O_CREAT` flag, the POSIX [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function requires a third argument, which is the mode to be used for the permissions on the created file.  The mode will be modified by the [`umask()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) setting.

Comment: @JimCastro, I'm calling `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` just to get the current offset, not change it.

Comment: No, not at all. The processes are _still_ [always] racing. You will get one of: `parent writes at 0 and ends with 6 ; child writes at 6 and ends with 8` or ... `child writes at 0 and ends with 2 ; parent writes at 2 and ends with 8`. The `write` calls are _atomic_. Even wrapping the writes in `flock(fd,LOCK_EX);` and `flock(fd,LOCK_UN)` will _not_ change that. Try: `pwrite(fd,buf,len,0);` in both and you _will_ get: `zzllo\n` regardless of the order because `pwrite` ignores the current file position in favor of the file position in the last argument.

Comment: @CraigEstey Ah, you're right. I misread what you said.

Comment: If parent/child did not share open file descriptors after a `fork()`, pipes would be rather difficult, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes have their own file descriptors but those act as reference-counted pointers to shared *open-file descriptions* (a separate open-file description is created for each `open`). The sharing of open-file descriptions is what allows, e.g., shell scripts to do stuff such as

```bash
(
 /usr/bin/echo hello
 /usr/bin/echo world 
) > some_file
```

and have `some_file` contain both `hello` and `world` without the latter overwriting the former (just like they wouldn't (without special effort) overwrite each other if they wrote to the terminal).

It also allows applications that modify terminal settings (`stty`), a utility such as `flock` (that places a lock into the shared file description), and possibly other stuff.